# Automatically generate XML-Documentation

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm not quite sure if this is possible, but I was wondering if Visual Studio 10 (2010) or 11 (2012) allows you to automatically generate an XML compliant documentation?

For example, in visual studio, if you are using the programming language C#, when you create a method, and type 3 forward slashes `/` - it generates a comment above the method with a place to fill in a summary, and descriptions for all parameters.

Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value1"></param>
/// <param name="value2"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int GetSum(int value1, int value2);
```

If not, is there an extension/tool that allows for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) and this style of comments are actually called "doxygen-comments".

Comment: I'm aware of this, but is there a tool that actually places a "fill-in" commenting template? Like what visual studio does for C# applications

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old thread. But if someone is still looking for this, ghostdoc is what you need  http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx